# programmatically generated pdf links working in chrome but not working in adobe reader

Tags: ios, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe-reader

I have generated pdf file programmatically through objective c language ios sdk.

links in this pdf files navigates to other page correctly in google chrome.
But not navigating correctly in adobe pdf reader 11.0.6.

What is the problem here.I have attached sample pdf files.Here is sample pdf file:

1. http://www.filedropper.com/mypdf1
2. http://www.filedropper.com/mypdf3

Comment: When I click on the links in Acrobat Pro XI on Mac OS X something happens. What exactly isn't working for you? Can you describe what the behaviour is that you don't like or that isn't correct?

Comment: It is not navigating to correct page.For first one mypdf1, when you click on first link 1.pngTo2.png it is navigating to page 3.ideally it should navigate to page2.To check correct behaviour of navigation open same pdf in google chrome,you can see correct navigation

Comment: even it works correctly when you put zoom level below 40 in adobe reader but if zoom level is more than 50% or it is set to actual size it navigates to wrong page

Comment: *when you click on first link 1.pngTo2.png it is navigating to page 3* - not exactly, at least not here... it shows the lower part of page 2 and (depending on the zoom level) some page three content. This is completely according to spec: **[ page /XYZ left top zoom ]** *Display the page designated by page, with the coordinates (left, top) positioned at the upper-left corner of the window and the contents of the page magnified by the factor zoom.*

Comment: yes,thanks for explaining.it works correctly when you open page in single page view.